# Account Validation Rule not working

Tags: validation, validation-rule, error, error-messages

I am working on a validation rule which appears to be simple but it is not working as expected.

The requirement is below.

when creating an account, if the account recordtype is "child", and if the parent account field is blank it should throw a validation error message.

Also, the error message should appear at the parent account field. However, parent account is not listed as one of the field in validation rule drop down.

Below is my validation rule code.

```
AND
(
$RecordType.Id = "0122000......",
ISNULL( ParentId ),
ISNEW()
)
```

Can someone help?

Comment: You need to use `ISBLANK` rather than `ISNULL`. Also `RecordType.DeveloperName` is far better than `RecordType.Id`.

Comment: I have tried both ISNULL and ISBLANK and it is not working in either case. We have had problems in the past with using DeveloperName as we are using multi-languages/locales.

Comment: DeveloperName should not vary across language nor locale, only labels can do that. You're going to have to be more specific than "not working". Please provide Minimum Viable Reproduction steps with the data you used as an example. Verify you have exactly the right Id, which again, is just a suboptimal way to implement filtering on RecordType.

Comment: Use of an explicit ID is not a robust way to do this and is not portable between orgs. You may find it works in one sandbox but not another. Use the developer name as @AdrianLarson recommended.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry, my bad. I was told that using the recordtype name was causing the problem. I have used the recordtype developer name in my validation rule and it is working fine now. Also, the validation rule was not working when I was using the 18 digit salesforce id of the child recordtype. When I switched 15 digit salesforce id the validation rule is started working. Anyway, now the validation rule is using the developer name of the recordtype and it is working good and I am going to leave it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Validate against `$RecordType.DeveloperName` rather than `$RecordType.Id`. This value is easier to guarantee you have correct (no 15 vs 18 digit issues), and it also remains the same between all orgs.